Alternate forms of Incomplete Beta function
The Beta function is given by $$ \mathcal{B}(z_1,z_2) = \int_0^1 t^{z_1-1}(1-t)^{z_2-1}dt = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{z_1-1}}{(1+t)^{z_1+z_2}}dt$$ for $\Re{(z_1)},\Re{(z_2)}>0$, and the incomplete beta function is given by $$ \mathcal{B}(v,z_1,z_2) = \int_0^v t^{z_1-1}(1-t)^{z_2-1}dt$$ for $0\le v\le 1$. For some $v>0$ and $\tilde{v}>0,\tilde{z}_1,\tilde{z}_2$ depending on $v$, is there a way to write $$I(v)= \int_0^{v} \frac{t^{z_1-1}}{(1+t)^{z_1+z_2}}dt \overset{?}{=} \mathcal{B}(\tilde{v},\tilde{z}_1,\tilde{z}_2).$$
I attempted to write out the Hypergeometric representations of both the functions,
$$ I(v)  = \frac{v^{z_1}}{z_1}{}_2F_1(z_1,z_1+z_2;1+z_1;-v)$$
$$ B(\tilde{v},\tilde{z}_1,\tilde{z}_2) = \frac{\tilde{v}^{\tilde{z}_1}}{\tilde{z}_1}{}_2F_1(\tilde{z}_1,1-\tilde{z}_2;1+\tilde{z}_1;\tilde{v}).$$
I can take $\tilde{z}_1 = z_1$ and $\tilde{z}_2 = 1-z_2-z_1$, but that would force $\tilde{v}=-v<0$ and give us an additional term $(-1)^{z_1}$. I am not sure if this is even the correct approach. Is there a way to write the integral $I(v)$ in terms of the incomplete beta function?

You can substitute $t+1\to t$, get a $(-1)^{z_1-1}$ factor, and use $B_x(a,b)=\int_0^x t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1}dt$

Or just substitute $\frac{t}{1+t}=x$ in $I(v)$, like it's done for the complete beta.

@metamorphy That's gold. I didn't realize this. Thank you.
